# Laravel Eloquent - find order

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I am getting 3 records from my database

```
  return \App\Work::find([12, 2, 3]);
```

The annoying thing is they are reordered by when I pass them the to the view.

Is there a way to retain the order they are 'found'?

Comment: Why aren't you using `orderBy`?

Comment: @AliGajani : orderBy will not work here, may be `sortBy` would do the trick

Comment: orderby asc or desc would not give me the desired results

Answer (score 1):

MySQL allows you to specify an order for a given field using this syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM work ORDER BY FIELD(id, 12, 2, 3);
```

Combine that with Eloquent's `orderByRaw()` method (https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orderByRaw) and you should be able to do something like this:

```
return \App\Work::whereIn('id', [12, 2, 3])->orderByRaw('FIELD (id, 12, 2, 3)')->get();
```

The `find()` method won't work with this because it returns the object immediately, so we need to use a `WHERE IN` clause for the ID instead. Obviously it will need a bit of refactoring as currently the ID's are duplicated, but this should achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sortBy` like this

```
return \App\Work::find([12, 2, 3])->sortBy(function($el){
    return array_search($el->getKey(), [12, 2, 3]);
}
```

About [getKey](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getKey)